# What does %* mean?

Tags: batch-file

I installed pychecker and noticed the batch file I should use to run pychecker has these entries:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe
```

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pychecker\checker.py %*
```

What does the second line mean?

Comment: Nothing to Python.  That's a line of DOS Shell command.  It's in a .BAT file, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does %\* mean in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144716/what-does-mean-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing isn't Python code. It is a Windows command script.

`%*` means pass all the arguments that you passed to the batch file.

Answer (score 4):

%* is the arguments that you pass to the batch file.
What ever arguments you pass to the batch file from the command line is in turn passed to checker.py.

If you call

> checker.bat myfile.py

then the lines in the batch file will be replaced as

> C:\Python26\python.exe
>
> C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pychecker\checker.py
>   myfiile.py

You can find more details [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything to python, it is being expanded by the shell (cmd.com). I think it's the arguments list passed to the batch file.