# What does %* mean in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have seen the usage of `%*` in batch files and command lines.

Can someone explain the typical usage of `%*` with an example?

Comment: @phuclv I really think the duplicate target direction should be reversed. This question seems like a better canonical than the one you linked to.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It means "all the parameters in the command line".

For example, it's useful when you want to forward the command line from your batch file to another program:

```
REM mybatchfile.cmd
echo You called this with arguments: %*
echo I will now forward these to the DIR command.
dir %*
```

Answer (score 33):

One important point not listed in any of the previous answers: `%*` expands to *all* parameters from the command line, even after a `SHIFT` operation.

Normally a `SHIFT` will move parameter `%2` to `%1`, `%3` to `%2`, etc., and `%1` is no longer available. But `%*` ignores any `SHIFT`, so the complete parameter list is always available. This can be both a blessing and a curse.

Answer (score 13):

`%*` expands to the complete list of arguments passed to the script.

You typically use it when you want to call some other program or script and pass the same arguments that were passed to your script.

Answer (score 5):

> The `%*` modifier is a unique modifier that represents all arguments passed in a batch file. You cannot use this modifier in combination with the `%~` modifier. The `%~` syntax must be terminated by a valid argument value.

Source:

- ["Using batch parameters" on Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) (defunct)
- ["Using batch parameters" (Archive.org mirror)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120021145/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: I added a link to the an archived version of the page. Please note that the documentation refers to Windows XP though. There might be different modifiers available for Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

It is also important to note that `%*` does not go through the parsing that the individual `%n` arguments do.  For example, if the parameters are:

> a "b c" j=k d,e,f

Then `ECHO %*` will display:

> a "b c" j=k d,e,f

But `ECHO 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5 6=%6 7=%7 8=%8 9=%9` will display:

> 1=A 2="B C" 3=J 4=K 5=D 6=E 7=F 8= 9=

The difference is how parameters which contain special characters, but are NOT enclosed in quotation marks, are handled.
The special characters are the usual suspects: space & ( ) [ ] { } ^ = ; ! ' + , ` ~