# How to run .phar from anywhere on Windows?

Tags: php, windows

I have .phar file and i want to run it from anywhere with this command.

**php file.phar --options**

where file.phar is in C:\my-php-cli\file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is not possible. For example, putting `file.phar` to `C:\Windows\System32` and calling `php file.phar --options` from another directory like `C:\Temp` will produce

```
Could not open input file: file.phar
```

You have to create a small batch file next to your *.phar, e.g., `run-file.bat` with this contents:

```
@ECHO OFF
php %~dp0file.phar %*
```

Then, calling `run-file` will execute your `file.phar`.

Comment: I think this need more info. Which part of `php %~dp0file.phar %*` gets replaces with the .phar filename? do we keep `~dp0`?

Comment: ~dp0 extract the path of run-file.bat
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work

%* forward the parameters from run-file.bat to file.phar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144716/what-does-mean-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 10 I found that you need a your-file.cmd to run the .phar file.

I was trying to get php-cs-fixer running so in my PHP directory i had the following:

```
PHP\
    phpFixer\
        php-cs-fixer.phar
        php-cs-fixer.cmd
```

Contents of php-cs-fixer.cmd:

```
@php "%~dp0php-cs-fixer.phar" %*
```

verified it works by entering this in command line:

```
php-cs-fixer --version
PHP CS Fixer 2.14.0 Sunrise by Fabien Potencier and Dariusz Ruminski (b788ea0)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add the folder containing **file.phar** to your path variable.

See [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for more information.

Comment: This isn't working properly, ran some tests in Powershell after adding the PHAR's folder to my PATH variable and I keep getting [this annoying popup](https://i.imgur.com/Js0hD3z.png). What worked is using @borek-bernard's suggestion and adding a .bat file, can OP confirm this solution indeed works?

Comment: This answer is 4 years old so it's likely things have changed since then. The other answer is only 1 year old.

Comment: Reply to old answer and old comment: @kutacoder calling `php file.phar` directly from its folder where .phar exists work **but** from my question is run it from **anywhere**. Example I have **C:\wp\wp.phar** call `php wp.phar` from **C:** will not working even the path was added to Windows env. Use @Borek Bernard answer is working fine until now. It is just like this since the day I post the question.

Answer (score 2):

To make `wp-cli.phar` work,

1. Create wp.bat
2. Put the following in it:

```
@ECHO OFF
php %~dpn0.phar %*
```

%~dpn0: Is a placeholder for $0 (Linux users will understand).

3. The directory where you want to place `wp.bat`, make sure to add that path to the environtment variables.
4. Rename `wp-cli.phar` to `wp.phar` (should be the same as the name of the `.bat` file, i.e. `wp.bat` and `wp.phar`. It is better to have both in the same directory.
5. Open a new PowerShell window, and execute

`wp --help`

The above command will only work if you have PHP installed.

Comment: Instead of renaming `wp-cli` to `wp`, which could lead to some unintentional misinterpretation in the future (ie thinking `wp.phar` is a file to do with the actual wp structure rather than the CLI), could we not just name the bat `wp-cli.bat`??

Comment: @Studocwho It is entirely up to you. I renamed it to keep the command same on my Windows and Linux systems. 

Comment: Yeah, it took me a long while after writing that comment to realise it's because of the command. (doh!)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make `.phar` files work the way `.bat` or `.vbs` files work where you can run them directly or add them to your path and it will automatically run them through the appropriate interpreter (in this case PHP)

1. Add `;.PHAR` to the end of your `PATHEXT` environment variable (searching "Edit the system environment variables" in the start menu should get you to the right place). This is a semicolon separated list of file extensions that will be run in the same command window rather than launching their own window.
2. Set the default program for `.phar` files to be `php.exe`. You can get to the settings for this by searching "Choose a default app for each type of file" in the start menu or by selecting "Try an app on this PC" > "Look for another app on this PC" in the dialogue that opens the first time you try to open a `.phar` file.
3. At this point you can run `.phar` files just like you would run a `.bat` file. You don't have to worry about what directory `php.exe` is in, but you **do** have to worry about what directory the `.phar` is in. If you want to make a particular `.phar` file available from any folder it needs to be inside a folder listed in your `PATH`. Either move the `.phar` to an existing folder in your `PATH` (like `C:\Windows\system32`) or add the folder containing the `.phar` to your `PATH` the same way you modified `PATHEXT` in step 1.
4. You have to close and re-open any cmd/powershell windows before environment variable changes go into effect.
5. Run your `.phar` file without putting `php` in front. If it is in your `PATH` you can optionally omit the `.phar` at the end as well. This is nice if you are using, for example, `composer.phar`. Once you set everything up and add it to your path, you can do things like `composer --version` from any directory.