# How to open goland from specific path?

Tags: go, goland

This is actually a straightforward question, have been researching on how to use such command like `code .` for VSCode , but with GoLand in Windows. Any help please?

Comment: Maybe try to add Goland folder to Windows PATH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoLand works in a similar way to VSCode as covered in [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/opening-files-from-command-line.html):

```
goland64 .
```

However for this to work the folder with `goland64.exe` will need to be in your [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows). You can test this without adding the folder to your path by specifying the full path to the executable; on my PC this is:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\GoLand 2021.3\bin\goland64.exe" .
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, another follow-up question can I change the command from `goland64` into anything else?

Comment: I guess you could rename `goland64.exe` but that is likely to break other things (e.g. shortcuts). An alternative would be to create a `.cmd` ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144756/11810946)) /`.ps1` file that calls `goland64.exe` and passes on the parameters.

Comment: Alternatively, you can download Toolbox App to manage your JetBrains IDEs installations and specify Shell script name in the settings per IDE.

Comment: is there a command to do this in MacOS?